# Writing in disjoint cycles

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Write $\left ( 123 \right )^{-1}\left ( 23 \right )\left ( 123 \right )$ in disjoint cycles.

I get that $\left ( 123 \right )^{-1}$=$\left ( 132 \right )$

$\left ( 132 \right )\left ( 23 \right )\left ( 123 \right )=\left ( 13 \right )\left ( 12 \right )\left ( 23 \right )\left ( 12 \right )\left ( 13 \right )$

Discounting the repeated cycles, I conclude the cycle is just $\left ( 23 \right )$. But this is wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot just discount the repeated cycles unless they all commute. You need to actually do the calculation.

Comment: I would like an example.

Comment: An example of what? You just need to write out what the given permutation does to each element and write this in the cycle notation.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft is right. You have only 3 indices. You are not required to work out a general solution, nor did you provide one here....

Comment: Starting from left:(1...)
3 get maps to 2 and 2 gets mapped to 3 and 3 gets maps to 2 in the last bracket.
So, (12). Which isn't correct.
I understand this is more mechanical than anything else but most of my efforts were spent on the less mechanical question of Gallian. This came from my tutorial. I am lost.

Comment: Do not go from left to right (unless Gallian does this, which he does not as far as I recall).

Comment: Indeed, Gallian does not. But this is a tutorial question (not from Gallian). The answer is (13).
Here's what I did(from left to right):
(1...) then 3 mapped to 2 in second bracket then mapped to 3 in third bracket. 
So, (13...). 
2 gets mapped to 3 in the second bracket then 3 gets mapped to 1 in the third bracket.
So, (132).
The answer is (13). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your error is in the conclusion. You consluded that $1$ maps to $3$ and $3$ maps to $1$ and somehow concluded that this was $(132)$.

Comment: I am really lost as to the process.
1 in first bracket to 2 in third bracket so (12)
3 in first bracket to 2 in second bracket to 3 in third bracket so (3)
And everything falls apart. I do not understand

Comment: Going from left to right, the first cycle (in the original form) sends 1 to 3, then the second cycle sends 3 to 2 and the third cycle sends 2 to 3. Then you continue with 3 (since this is where you ended up). The first cycle sends 3 to 2, then the second sends 2 to 3 and the third sends 3 to 1, so you have the cycle $(13)$. 2 is sent to 1 then 1 is fixed by the middle and sent to 2 by the last, so 2 is indeed fixed which means that the final conclusion is that the product is $(13)$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Gonna favourite this.